# Dropdown Menu Bar Slidedown Unexpected Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just added my entire page because the menubar wasn't shown in full.  Still need help with why the slide animation only occurs on first mouse over.

I am trying to make my drop down menu that on hover uses jquery's slideDown and slideUp functions.  I have it working... kinda. The menubar tends to not apply the effect on first hover, and then do the effect afterward.  Then it does the slideUp, slideDown, slideUp...... over and over again a few times. I have tried wrapping the function in a document ready function.  I also tried adding a truthy if statement so that mouse out only works if the menu is down.  I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Just realized on mouseout is a bad idea because when a user moves down my dropdown menu it will scroll up aswell... any recommendations on another way to do this?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle slideDown" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <div class="transparent vert-center">
    <h1 id="heading-title">Website Heading</h1>
      <p id="heading-desc">Information about the website!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

            </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass size"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus size"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-bottom outline-above">
    <div class="container-fluid footer-bottom footer-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="footer-heading footer-top">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" id="button-margin-top1" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center outline">
                <h3 class="footer-heading footer-top">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" id="button-margin-top2" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h3 class="footer-heading footer-top">Footer Title</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
                <button type="button" id="button-margin-top3" class="btn-success btn-format">Click</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideDown(250);
});

///if ($(.dropdown-menu).height(){
$('.dropdown').mouseout(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp(250);
});
});
 ///   })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Top nav syling */
.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgb(54, 135, 2);
    font-size: 120%;
}

/*Main display styling */

.jumbotron{
    height: 400px;
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 96%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(79, 201,2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/*Navbar font coloring */
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: white;
}

/* Centers content vertically */
.vert-center{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/*Styles partially transparent background within jumbotron class */
.transparent{
    background: rgba(190, 200, 216,.5);
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    width: 60%;
}

/*Padding around desc within jumbotron */
#heading-desc {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/*Padding around title within jumbotron */
#heading-title{
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Bootstrap menu created using bootstrapdesigntools.com */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: rgba(54, 135, 2, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 0%, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(90, 224, 4, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(68, 168, 5, 1);
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #44a805;
}

/*Styling of icons */
.size{
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/*Outline surrounding three columns including icons */
.outline {
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(79, 201, 2);
}
.navbar-bottom {
    background-color: rgba(222, 223, 224, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 223, 224, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 223, 224, 1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.btn-format {
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 6%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.horizontal-center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}
}
.footer-heading {
    font-size: 150px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
footer-title-pad {
    padding-top: 2px;
}


#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}
/*Styles active tab of top menu bar */
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(57, 145, 3, 1));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 145, 3, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(54, 135, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 145, 3, 1) 100%);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {

    background-color: #42a503;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #42a503;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #2fc474;
}
.navbar-bottom button {
  margin: auto;
}
.footer-bottom{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.footer-top {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
/*Upper outline on bottom navigation bar*/
.outline-above {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(79, 201,2);
}
/*Spacing between buttons in footer, error- needs more efficient  class */
#button-margin-top1 {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
#button-margin-top2 {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
#button-margin-top3 {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
/*dropdown menu background color */
.dropdown-menu{
    background-color: rgba(47, 196, 116, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(67, 171, 3, .93) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, .93) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(67, 171, 3, .93) 0%, rgba(47, 196, 116, .93) 100%);
}
/*Dropdown menu on hover instead of click unless screen has been resized */
@media (min-width: 979px){
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    }
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus{
    background-color: rgba(68, 229, 74, 1);
}
/*Changes dropdown menu icon on screen resize */
.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    background-color: rgba(44, 226, 50, 1);
}
.dropdown>a {
  display: block;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideDown(750);
});

///if ($(.dropdown-menu).height(){
$('.dropdown').mouseout(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(750);
});
});
 ///   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the everytime u hover on and off the animation will qeue up a few times that's why you see that repeat up and down motion. Just put a `stop()` before the animation like this

`$('.dropdown-menu').stop().slideUp(750);`

You need to do this for slideUp too

You can see it all in action
[**Here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/VpBOxe).

and i'd recommend making the dropdown a text display block and maybe increasing the padding as it is really easy to unhover.

Comment: Thank you!  How would I turn the drop down into a text display block?  Also is there a way to make it so the mouseout applies to the drop down menu and button as well?  Would it be similar to css selectioning multiple elements like $('.class1','.class2')

Comment: You just style the `.dropdown a` in the css i've done it in the example just can see it at the top. As for the mouseout i think you'd have it apply it separately but not 100% sure though. If the answer helped in any way be sure to accept it as the correct one so other people know it solved the problem :)

Comment: After adding the stop it still does not use the animation on the first mouse over.  I can't see how it's done in your code.  I'll mark it as correct once I have it working on first mouse over, thank you for the help!